# Unix using awk and cut together

Tags: bash, unix, awk, cut

I am trying to get netstat, awk, and cut to work together to parse two parts of netstat output

I want to pull only the last 4 numbers of the first column:

```
 11.111.222.32.3433   
 10.204.101.85.3433
 10.204.101.85.3433
```

Which I am able to do:

```
netstat -an |grep 3433 |awk '{print $1}' | cut -d "." -f5
```

But I also want to print the second column but leave off the last 4 numbers

example:

```
 33.44.444.43.5555   
 24.204.101.85.3434
 11.204.101.85.6533
```

So I want the final output to look like

```
3433 | 33.44.444.43
3433 | 24.204.101.85
3433 | 11.204.101.85
```

I tried to combine two awks but I get an error

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make sense with your requirement! Can you re-check it once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for my system it was col 4, and 5 so following worked for me:

```
$ netstat -an|grep 3433|awk '{print $4,"|",$5}'|sed s/:/./g|cut -d '.' -f5-8
```

as you have described your data, this should work for you

```
$ netstat -an|grep 3433|awk '{print $1,"|",$2}'|cut -d '.' -f5-8
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You never need grep, sed or cut when you're using awk so while this may produce the output you expect, it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can cut in awk using awk's function `split`. You can also filter records using a regex condition within awk, making `grep` and `cut` superfluous.

Something like the following should get you close:

```
 netstat -an  | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" | "} $1~/3433$/{split($1,a,"."); split($2,b,"."); print a[5], b[1]"."b[2]"."b[3]"."b[4] }'
```

This breaks down like:

1. Set the output field separator to be a pipe between two spaces
2. Check the first field to see if it ends with `3433`
3. Split the first field by a period and store the results in array named `a`
4. Split the second field by a period and store it's results in array named `b`
5. Print out the 5th element of array `a`, followed by the OFS, and then the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th elements of array `b` with a period between them.

You can also have awk determine a distinct field by using more than one delimiter, which may fit here too, depending on your needs.

This would look something like:

```
 netstat -an  | awk -F"[ .]" 'BEGIN{OFS="."} $5=="3433" { print $5" | " $6,$7,$8,$9}'
```

Answer (score 0):

direct replacement of your grep in `awk`

```
$ ... | awk -v OFS=' | ' '/3433/{sub(/.*\./,"",$1); sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"",$2)}1'

3433 | 33.44.444.43
3433 | 24.204.101.85
3433 | 11.204.101.85
```

however, you should be checking `$1~/3433$/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sed`:

```
echo " 33.44.444.43.5555
 24.204.101.85.3434
 11.204.101.85.6533" | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\([^.]*\)$/\2 | \1/'
```